# Webpack and programmatically injected content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing a Chrome extension using React and Webpack.

In this project, different modules will programmatically inject content scripts using `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content-script-file.js'})`.

This becomes problematic since I'm using Webpack for bundling everything. Basically, the background script is loading a number of modules, which are all configured to inject content scripts programmatically under certain circumstances.

However, I can't figure out how these content scripts will be "found" in the bundled application. They aren't ever explicitly imported, just referenced in `executeScript` calls.

At the same time, the content scripts use React, so they have to go through the `babel-loader` in Webpack.

Any ideas?

Comment: So basically you'll have to make a wrapper function that injects babel script (arguably a very large one) then the actual content script (and probably the code that triggers babel)... Aren't you afraid the overhead could be too big?

Comment: @wOxxOm: I would like to avoid that kind of bloat to be honest, but I'm new to Webpack, so I'm not sure what it can do for me to prevent that.

Comment: The efficient approach would be to inject precompiled scripts. I guess you'll have to manually define a list of scripts to precompile but I'm no expert on webpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content scripts are effectively "entry points" in webpack-terms.

Each top-level content script should be defined as a webpack entry.
Use webpack to build these content scripts.  Each entry will pull in all of its dependencies (like React) into one big blob.

You then make a 2nd webpack build that builds your extension.  This extension will use the raw loader and `import` your webpack-compiled content scripts and then it will have them all as strings local variables:

```
import scriptA from 'content/build/a';
import scriptB from 'content/build/b';
```

And now you can inject the scripts into your tabs as needed:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, scriptA);
```

Comment: Can you help me find an example of what you're talking about regarding the 2nd webpack build?

Answer (score -2):

This should work, the chrome docs say execute script excepts string code or string file.

```js
import ContentScript from './content-script-file';

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, ContentScript);
```

Comment: A question is by definition not an answer, therefor this should be a comment, not an answer